# flot x axis as string

Tags: jquery, flot

this is the data i want to plot with flot (jquery library )

where action is on the x axis and the count on the y

```
var data= [{"action":"QUERY INSURANCE","count":"9"},{"action":"QUERY POLICE DETAILS","count":"15"},{"action":"QUERY VEHICLE DETAILS","count":"3"},{"action":"CIVILIAN DETAILS","count":"1"},{"action":"LOGGING IN","count":"59"},{"action":"Report Occurrence","count":"1"},{"action":"QUERY CRIMINAL RECORDS","count":"2"},{"action":"QUERY VEHICLE OFFENCES","count":"2"},{"action":"QUERY DL VALIDITY","count":"5"},{"action":"REPORT OCCURRENCE","count":"23"}];

$.plot($("#plotrr"), [
    {
        data: data,
        bars: { show: true }

    }]);
```

how do i show the 'action' on the x axis  and the 'count' on the y axis

Comment: Have you looked at the `flot` [API documentation](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt)?

Comment: yes i have , probably not well enough but i didn't get how to do that from there

Answer (score 8):

What you need to do is specify the `ticks` parameter for the `xaxis` in the flot options and set each of your actions as one of the ticks.  So you'll do something like 0 = Query Insurance, 1 = Query Police Details, etc:

```
$.plot($("#plotrr"), [
    {
        data: [[0,9],[1,15] ... ], //fill out the rest of your counts sequentially here
        bars: { show: true }

    }], 
    //flot options
    {
        xaxis: {
           ticks: [[0,'Query Insurance'],[1,'Query Police Details'] ...] //fill out the rest here
        }
    });
```

One other caveat is that it looks like your counts are strings when they should be numbers - i.e. `count: "9"` is wrong, `count: 9` is right.